# javafx, how to implement confirmHandler?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I'm using javafx's webengine to display a web page. And on the page, there's script calling window.confirm. I already know how to set the confirm handler and how to show a modal-like dialog.

My question is how can I get the user's choice before handler returns?

```
webEngine.setConfirmHandler(new Callback<String, Boolean>() {
@Override
public Boolean call(String message) {
// Show the dialog
...
return true; // How can I get user's choice here?
}
});
```

Comment: OK. Blocking will be available in 2.2. Have to wait...http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19783

Comment: Why don't you put your answer in a comment and mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @jschoen Because 2.2 hasn't been released yet. But I'll write down my findings in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19783](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19783), we can use the new method showAndWait which is available in JavaFx 2.2 to achieve this.

> Stage class:
>
> ```
> /** 
>  * Show the stage and wait for it to be closed before returning to the 
>  * caller. This must be called on the FX Application thread. The stage 
>  * must not already be visible prior to calling this method. This must not 
>  * be called on the primary stage. 
>  * 
>  * @throws IllegalStateException if this method is called on a thread 
>  * other than the JavaFX Application Thread. 
>  * @throws IllegalStateException if this method is called on the 
>  * primary stage. 
>  * @throws IllegalStateException if this stage is already showing. 
>  */ 
> public void showAndWait();
> ```

@jewelsea created a sample on https://gist.github.com/2992072. Thanks!